# Best way to send Customer and Order data from SQL server to MongoDB along with hyperlinks

Tags: c#, mongodb

**Problem Statement:**
I need to get Customer and all their corresponding Orders stored in the following format in `MongoDB`.
Current data resides in 2 different tables - Customers and Orders in `MSSQL` database.

**Expected Collection in MongoDb:**

```
{
  "_data": [
    {
      "customer": {
        "customerID": "1240014902244000006",
        "firstName": "Jerry",
        "surname": "Galoski",
        "orders": [
          {
            "_data": {
              "orderId": "1240014912244000016",
              "suburb": "Delhi",
              "postcode": "110051",
              "country": "India"
            },
            "_links": [
              {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "/customer/1240014902244000006/orders",
                "action": "GET"
              },
              {
                "rel": "customer",
                "href": "/customer/1240014902244000006",
                "action": "GET"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_data": {
              "orderId": "1240014912244000024",
              "suburb": "Delhi",
              "postcode": "110051",
              "country": "India"
            },
            "_links": [
              {
                "rel": "customer",
                "href": "/customer/1240014902244000006/orders",
                "action": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "/customer/1240014902244000006",
          "action": "GET"
        },
        {
          "rel": "orders",
          "href": "/customer/1240014902244000006/orders",
          "action": "GET"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Steps taken to achieve this:**

1. First step is to collate all orders data, which I'm doing using the below SQL query:

```
SELECT CustomerId, AllOrderIds =
STUFF(
(
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(e2.OrderId AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM CustomerOrderRelation e2
WHERE e1.CustomerId = e2.CustomerId
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1,1,''
) FROM CustomerOrderRelation cor;
```

[image]

2. Then I use the above subquery in the customers sql query to get the complete output as shown.
   [image]
3. Then in the C# code, I will process the Customer records one by one, to generate the hyperlinks for each.
4. I need to generate hyperlinks for Order records also.
5. Once I have the hyperlinks generated in C#, I will call `InsertMany` command (MongoDB) to insert data. As a result, I will have 2 collections created in MongoDb - one each for Customer and Order.
6. Finally, I'll be using MongoDb's MapReduce functionality to merge 2 collections to get the data.

```
db.customers.mapReduce(mapCustomers, reduce, {"out": {"reduce": "customerId"}});
db.orders.mapReduce(mapOrders, reduce, {"out": {"reduce": "customerId"}});
db.customerAndOrders.find().pretty();
```

7. I need to do the merge because, I am not finding a clever way to do following operations:

- Get customers and their consolidated orders in one single entity
- Generate Hyperlinks for customers and all their orders
- Push this data into MongoDb with customer details and their order details

**Suggestion required:**
Is there a better way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Another way would be to export SQL data from tables to CSV (or JSON is even better). Then import (using `mongoimport`) the CSV/JSON into the MongoDB - each CSV/JSON mapped to a collection. Then, use an aggregation query to transform/merge the data into a single collection. See aggregation's `$lookup`, `$out` and `$merge` stages.